# Override Android Gestures System

Tags: java, android, gesture

I need to develop a tweak that let me use some gestures in every part of the system so they must be valid in the launcher and in every app that I launch.

I think that I must override the basic android recognize touch system... and re-write part of them.

Wich are the method responsable of what I want?
Can someone post me one example of how do that?
I saw that some custom launcher (like the LG phones) use them.

Comment: What you will need to do is "re-write part of" the operating system, creating your own ROM mod, that implements what you want, if you want to affect all applications. "one example" of this is **massively** beyond the scope of a StackOveflow question.

Comment: the only solution is a ROM? is not possible to create a simple tweak? I need to recognize only "the down from up" gesture.

Comment: You cannot intercept touch events from other apps *and* have those other apps get those same touch events, for privacy and security reasons. It is possible to create an app that responds to touch events on top of all other apps, but whatever "zone" represents the place where you want to start those touch events is unavailable to other apps. If you want *both* to handle these gestures *and* not interfere with the underlying app, then you need to modify the OS.

Comment: The zone solution I think will ne enough! Can you suggest how van I do that?

Comment: I do not have complete and current techniques, but you will want to research specific window types like a "system alert window".